# AutoMapper recursive

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to make a deep copy of a complex object tree using AutoMapper.
The problem is that for each member  I would like to construct a new object and then map it, and not simply copying the existing one.
Here it is an example:

```
public abstract class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    }

    public class OuterTest : Test
    {
        public InnerTest Inner { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerTest : Test
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and how to test it:

```
OuterTest outerDest = Mapper.Map<OuterTest, OuterTest>(outerSource);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InnerSource id: " + innerSource.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InnerSource value: " + innerSource.Value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OuterSource id: " + outerSource.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OuterDest id: " + outerDest.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OuterDest.Inner id: " + outerDest.Inner.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OuterDest.Inner value: " + outerDest.Inner.Value);
```

This is the result from the output window:

```
InnerSource id: a60fda37-206a-40a8-a7f8-db480149c906
InnerSource value: 2119686684
OuterSource id: 7486899e-2da8-4873-9160-d6096b555c73
OuterDest id: 7486899e-2da8-4873-9160-d6096b555c73
OuterDest.Inner id: a60fda37-206a-40a8-a7f8-db480149c906
OuterDest.Inner value: 2119686684
```

The problem is thet the object innerSource is always the same instance as outerDest.Inner (I verified through MakeObjectId of VS debugger) but I would like them to be two different instances.

How could I create a recursive map with this behavior? I tried creating a custom IValueResolver like the following, without success.

```
 public class AutoMapperNewObjectResolver : IValueResolver
        {
            public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
            {
                object resolved;
                if (source.Value != null)
                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(source.MemberType);
                    resolved = Mapper.Map(source.Value, instance, source.MemberType, source.MemberType);
                }
                else
                {
                    resolved = null;
                }
                ResolutionResult result = source.New(resolved, source.Context.DestinationType);
                return result;


   }
    }
```

and configured like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OuterTest, OuterTest>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Inner, o => o.ResolveUsing<AutoMapperNewObjectResolver>().FromMember(src => src.Inner));
```

Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: you can do this with ValueInjecter http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/, you're gonna need to use Activator inside a injection before setting the value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)